# Outlook 365 repeatedly asks for credentials, but still getting mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook 365 repeatedly asks for users credentials.
Adding the correct credentials does not stop the pop-ups, and the user is still able to send & receive emails.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you say "repeatedly" asks for credentials, is this while O365 is open or does it only pop-up when you open O365 for the first time?

Comment: While the application is open.

Comment: Have you tried disabling any add-ins? Something could be trying to authenticate and failing. Since mail is still flowing, that seems like the most likely cause.

Comment: Does it say "Connected to Microsoft Exchange" in the bottom right of the Outlook window?

Comment: I've disabled all add-ons and still no luck

Comment: And the message at the bottom of the window fluctuates between, "connected" and "need password"

Comment: How about changing the registry: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover]
"ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint"=dword:00000001